Mount a volume to `/mnt/foo`
At work my team has some scripts written for Linux which assume /mnt/foo exists, and I'd like to make them just work on my machine. But, / is a read-only file system, so I can't sudo mkdir /mnt . I can sudo echo "mnt" > /etc/synthetic.conf && sudo reboot and get a /mnt directory...but THAT is mounted as read-only and I can't create files in it. I just want /mnt/foo to redirect to /Volumes/foo (mounted via the GUI).

# make a directory for your mounts
$ sudo mkdir /private/mnt

# configure a root alias to that directory
$ sudo nano /etc/synthetic.conf
# add a line "mnt   private/mnt" separated by tab character

# apply the changes, without needing to reboot
$ /System/Library/Filesystems/apfs.fs/Contents/Resources/apfs.util -t

In other words, the format for synthetic.conf is a tab-delimited list of root names, and what they should be aliased to. And you must either reboot for changes to take effect, or run apfs.util -t.
At this point /mnt is a link to /private/mnt, which IS writeable, and one can do (among other things):
$ sudo ln -s /Volumes/foo /mnt/foo
$ open /mnt/foo/some/path/to/file.txt

and it works! (tested on macOS Sequoia, 15.1)

Thanks for self answering. For which version(s) of macOS does this work?

Your solution is fine as long as there is not already a synthetic.conf file with other entries. In that case, you would need to use >> in place of > to avoid overwriting it.

@LincDavis Good point. Fixed.

I don't see how the sudo echo will work, since only the echo is run as root, but the >> is performed by the current shell, as the (hopefully not-root) user. And indeed it doesn't -ksh: /etc/synthetic.conf: cannot create [Permission denied]. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/4337/340528 for a solution. And note that /etc/synthetic.conf was introduced in macOS Catalina, so this should work (once fixed) for Catalina and beyond.

@user7761803 Thanks for pointing that out. My mistake for trying to express the edit in a terse way, but without actually testing it. I've modified my instructions to simply use sudo nano.
